# How to enable internationalization in spring application which use spring security and thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have developed an application which runs using spring boot enabled security and thymeleaf as ui Templating

I tried enabling i18n in spring using interceptor in the configuration file which can be viewed [here](http://github.com/rajadileepkolli/springsecuredthymeleafapp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/learning/securedapp/configuration/WebConfiguration.java)

What am I missing here??

Note :: adding  @Enablemvc also didn't work

Comment: You are using Spring Boot and your configuration shows that you are very hard trying not to. Why?

Comment: I tried default initially only when things are not working I have added few beans that are necessary

Comment: Agreed, viewcontrollers and resourcehandlers are not necessary but I want my handlers to cache hence added that bean.

Comment: If you want caching just add `spring.resources.cache-period=<period-to-cache>` no need to override it. You are using Spring Security but also configure container security? Why? The connector you are configuring is already the default, so your tomcat config doesn't really add anything.

Comment: Thanks for the review I will remove those beans, could you check my configuration and let me know why my i18n is not working??   I tried by removing messages bean and tried initializing from application.properties in vain

Comment: What isn't working... The interceptor for changing the language will never work with spring security. For the simple fact it will never reach it, spring security is using servlet filters and as such are handled before it even has a change to reach the `DispatcherServlet`. Your configured message source (which again is already configured by default) will automatically be injected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116403/discussion-between-rajadilipkolli-and-m-deinum).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478321/spring-security-i18n-how-to-make-it-work-together for some hints.

Answer (score -1):

This is incorrect in your MessagesConfig configuration:

```
private static final String MESSAGES_BASENAME = "messages";
```

It's gotta be:

```
private static final String MESSAGES_BASENAME = "classpath:messages";
```

according to where you have located your files